# How to add results of a foreach loop to a variable in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, variables, foreach

```
foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) {      
    $items = $cart_itm["code"]
    . " - " . $cart_itm["qty"]
    . " - "  . $cart_itm["price"]
    . "<br>" ;

    echo $items;
}
```

I have this code which gets every item from my basket and displays them,  the problem is when I try to use this variable elsewhere in my code, it only displays the last item in the array, I realised that this is becasue the for loop keeps overwriting the last value . Is there a way I could put all results into one variable or use the loop to assign them too different variables maybe?

I also tried to put

```
foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) {      
    $items .= $cart_itm["code"]
    . " - " . $cart_itm["qty"]
    . " - " . $cart_itm["price"]
    . "<br>" ;

    echo $items;
}
```

after looking through the forum but that returns me with items is not defined

so I tried to put

```
$items= ("")
```

but still get the final result
Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: BTW: If you didn't already saw it you can take a tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see how the site works

Answer (score 5):

You can concatenate you variables together, but you have to initialize your variable first.

(Otherwise you can think of something like: 'I want to concatenate this string to nothing', so this is obvious not going to work, that's why you initialize your variable so, you can say: 'I want to concatenate this string to a empty string')

Something like this:

```
$items = "";
foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) {      
    $items .= $cart_itm["code"] . " - " . $cart_itm["qty"] . " - "  . $cart_itm["price"] . "<br>" ;
}
```

Or you can put them in a array with this:

```
$items = array();
foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) {      
    $items[] = $cart_itm["code"] . " - " . $cart_itm["qty"] . " - "  . $cart_itm["price"] . "<br>" ;

}

print_r($items);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$items = "";
foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) {      
$items .= $cart_itm["code"] . " - " . $cart_itm["qty"] . " - "  . $cart_itm["price"] . "<br>" ;

}

echo $items;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$foo = '';
foreach ($loopable as $item) {      
$foo = $foo.'-'.$item;
}
echo $foo;
```

Make sure to init that variable before the for loop